# How to get exception/ error that raise by HttpWebrequest for Wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, asynchronous

There are times that server shutdown, file missing on server and other problem. So, I want to trap or catch the exception thrown by HttpWebRequest when using Dispatcher thread to update content on UI.

The below code is unable to catch error and display in MessageBox.show(). Can anyone show me what I need to do? Thanks

```
    HttpWebRequest webReq;
    HttpWebResponse webResp;

    public void GetInfo(string Url)
    {
        webReq = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(Url);

        try
        {
            webReq.BeginGetResponse(OnGetBuffer, this);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    } 

    public void OnGetBuffer(IAsyncResult asr)
    {
        webResp = (HttpWebResponse)webReq.EndGetResponse(asr);

        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            Stream streamResult = webResp.GetResponseStream();

            try
            {

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: @Richard Schneider i wish more people realised this

Answer (score 1):

Place a try/catch around the .EndGetResponse() call.  I believe this is where the exception is being thrown.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I hope you don't intend to catch all exceptions and ignore them all. You would be ignoring exceptions that have nothing to do with your network connection failing.

Second, you need to place the try/catch around the code that might throw the exception:

```
public void OnGetBuffer(IAsyncResult asr)
{
    HttpWebResponse webResp;
    try
    {
        webResp = (HttpWebResponse)webReq.EndGetResponse(asr);
    }
    Catch (WebException ex)
    {
        // Do something to decide whether to retry, then retry or else
        throw; // Re-throw if you're not going to handle the exception
    }

    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        using (Stream streamResult = webResp.GetResponseStream())
        {
            // Do something with the stream
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I have tried all combination of Try-statement in all possible scenario. No can do. It seems the dispatcher lock out the thread.  I will give up on this method and try other way. Thank anyway.

Answer (score 0):

try using the [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) object. Then in the completed event handler the error is returned as `e.Error`

Comment: Thank. Know about this but I need to use HttpWebRequest.